# How to post image on twitter in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my app i want to integrate twitter.I also want to upload images through this twitter.Is there any open source for posting the images through twitter in iphone app.Can any one help me this issue.

Comment: why dont you use twitter framework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code in ios 5.0 (and greater) to post photo to twitter account using twitter framework.

```
if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"text to send"];
    [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageToSend"]];

    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];

    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)  {
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      switch (result) {
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            break;
        default:
            break;
       }
     };
   }else
   {
    // you can show alert here
   }
```

Comment: But it is for ios5 not for lower version